# Wait for multiple Alamofire request

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

I'm trying to add data to my data model so to test it I'm printing the info fetched via Alamofire but my problem is since some data needs to call the api again it becomes null when I print it. Here's my code

**Code for getting the person's data**

```
func printAPI(){

swApiHandler.requestSWPApi("http://swapi.co/api/people", completionHandler: {(response, error) in

    let json = JSON(response!)
    let jsonResult = json["results"]

    for (index,person):(String, JSON) in jsonResult{
        let name = person["name"].stringValue
        let height = person["height"].intValue
        let mass = person["mass"].intValue
        let hairColor = person["hair_color"].stringValue
        let skinColor = person["skin_color"].stringValue
        let eyeColor = person["eye_color"].stringValue
        let birthYear = person["birth_year"].stringValue
        let gender = person["gender"].stringValue
        let homeWorldUrl = person["homeworld"].stringValue
        let homeWorldNameKey = "name"
        let homeWorld = self.getSWApiSpecificValue(homeWorldUrl, strKey: homeWorldNameKey)

        print("Name: \(name)")
        print("Height: \(height)")
        print("Mass: \(mass)")
        print("Hair Color: \(hairColor)")
        print("Skin Color: \(skinColor)")
        print("Eye Color: \(eyeColor)")
        print("Birth Year: \(birthYear)")
        print("Gender: \(gender)")
        print("Home World: \(homeWorld)")
        print("------------------------------")
    }
})

}
```

**Code for getting the specific value**

```
  func getSWApiSpecificValue(strUrl: String, strKey: String) -> String{
    var name = ""
    swApiHandler.requestSWPApi(strUrl, completionHandler: {(response,error) in
        let json = JSON(response!)
        print(json[strKey].stringValue)
        name = json[strKey].stringValue
    })

    return name
}
```

If you want to know the JSON Model here it is

[image: JSON Model]

And for running the code here's the output
[image: Output]

Comment: Put breakpoints into your completion handlers and return statements and try to debug the app.

Comment: @Pooja Look at Homeworld the value is empty because it's being fetched asynchronously (Nested Api Call)

Comment: use blocks so that statements written after API call will execute after response of the API

Comment: @Pooja I'm new to Swift Development can you tell me on how to achieve that based on my code above?

Answer (score 1):

You should make your api call in background and after it's finished populate your data on main queue.
Just change your code to get specific value to this one:

```
func getSWApiSpecificValue(strUrl: String, strKey: String) -> String{
  var name = ""
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0)) { () -> Void in
swApiHandler.requestSWPApi(strUrl, completionHandler: {(response,error) in
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
      let json = JSON(response!)
      print(json[strKey].stringValue)
      name = json[strKey].stringValue
      return name
    }
  })
 }
}
```

In code above first you get make a request to the server in `background` and if you get response in `main` queue will populate you `variable name`.
Also it's better to change your api call function to something like that:

```
func getDataFromServer(ulr: String, success: (([AnyObject]) -> Void)?, failure: (error: ErrorType) -> Void){
}
```

In this way you can handle your errors and if success get your data.

Comment: wow! glad you commented in my post. I'll check this code tomorrow morning and see if it works, btw.. thanks for the suggestion. It would be very useful for my code :D